# What is the best way to create table for comments/Posts in a website

Tags: mysql

i'm creating a website where user can post some text and may be  attached with maximum one photo and users can comment/ like

what is the best way to create tables in my database representing these entities / actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the solution would involve some relations between tables.

I'd firstly, want my code to be as extendable as possible, so I would have a thread table.

```
ThreadID   ThreadData
-------------------------------
1          Favourite languages
2          Favourite Programmers
```

Secondly I'd have some sort of posts table, with a foreign key relationship to the thread table:

```
PostID    PostData    TimeStamp    User    ThreadID
--------------------------------------------------------------
1         C# ftw!!    07/04/2013   Chris   1
2         Adi Shamir  07/04/2013   Chris   2
```

See how you can link all the posts to the threads this way. Now you can't be sure if a user will post a photo, so I wouldn't have a `photo` field in your posts table, because you want to avoid NULL values, so your tables are fully normalized. This implies a `Photo` table, with a foreign key relationship to the `Post` table.

```
PhotoID    PhotoLocation       PostID
------------------------------------------------
1          img/adishamir.jpg   2
```

Then you simply load the photo when you load the post.

Finally for likes, it's very similar to the photo table. A LikeID and a post to like.

Then it's up to you to write the code that displays this data in a meaningful way! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by looking at existing packages that do the sorts of things you're talking about.  If the existing package for some reason can't be modified to suit your purposes, then look at the code and database setup to see how they do it.

Don't start projects with a blank sheet of paper and come in and say "Hey, how do I do this big involved complicated task?"

Comment: can you help me where i can find such packages !